# Magento 2 Customer Scope Global and shipping countries

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-address, global

I have a Magento 2.3 website that has many websites created, and I want to set the **Customer Scope** to ***Global*** so they can log into all websites with one login. But I still want to limit the shiping counties to each country. Is this possible? it seems like when I change customer scop til ***Global***, then all countries are available from the dropdown list on the checkout page.

Answer (score -2):

On the `Admin sidebar`, go to `Stores > Settings > Configuration`.

In the left panel, expand `Customers` and choose `Customer Configuration`.

Expand Expansion selector the `Account Sharing Options section`.

**Account Sharing Options**

Set Share Customer Accounts to one of the following:

1. Global   Shares customer account information with every website and store in the Magento installation.
2. Per Website  Limits customer account information to the website where the account was created.
3. If necessary, clear the User system value checkbox to make the change.

When complete, click Save Config.

If your Magento installation has a hierarchy of websites, stores, or views, you can set the context, or “scope” of a configuration setting to apply to a specific part of the installation.